# If-else in where condition - MySQL

Tags: mysql, if-statement, where-clause

I've data ike this

> 1. PX01 , Dony, ASUS , Area1
> 2. PX01 , Dony, ACER , Area1
> 3. PX01 , Dony, SONY , Area1
> 4. PX02 , ROKY, ASUS , Area2
> 5. PX03 , Steve, ASUS , Area1

I want select data IF(Area2) Just Asus, but if(Area1) Asus and SONY.
How to write if else in the where part of my query.

Sample

```
SELECT 
    .....  
WHERE if(Area = 'Area1') { PRODUCT = ASUS AND SONY} 
IF(Area = 'Area2' ) { PRODUCT = ASUS }  
IF(Area = 'Area3' ) { PRODUCT = SONY }
```

Comment: Please include the _exact_ output you are expecting here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT {columns list}
FROM {table name}
WHERE CASE Area WHEN 'Area1' THEN Product IN ('ASUS', 'SONY')
                WHEN 'Area2' THEN Product = 'ASUS'
                WHEN 'Area3' THEN Product = 'SONY'
                             ELSE NULL
                             END;
```